# Prepare Failed on Mediaplayer when trying to stream

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to stream an MP3-file with the following code in Android 2.3.3:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();  
String uri = "http://192.168.2.102:8080/sound/test.mp3";  
player.setDataSource(uri);  
player.prepare();
```

for some reason every time I call prepare I get the following IOException: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
I tested the link directly in a browser and it works.
I also added the Internet permission in the manifest.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

thanks for the help

Comment: That URL looks to me like a local address. You can't access it like that from the emulator, and neither from the phone.

Comment: why can I not access this file with this ip from my phone? My phone is in the same network as my server. so it should work, just is I can access content on a local server running in the same network. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that there was no ID3 tag attached to the MP3 file I was trying to stream, and Android doesn't like that...